# Lambda expression anonymous object life cycle

Tags: java, object, lambda, garbage-collection, lifecycle

My question is about handling and life cycle of the anonymous object in JVM 1.8.

As far as I read, in JDK 1.8, the underlying mechanism of lambda expression isn't purely function based. I.e. it still create an anonymous object with the method we defined in the code and call that method upon the anonymous object. Also, because the lambda expression doesn't introduce any new variable scope, calling "this" in the lambda expression would refer to the original object instead of such anonymous method.

Naturally the question follows: how does JVM handle the life cycle of such anonymous object? Define the object method containing such lambda expression as "outer object method", At least I have the following questions.

1. If the outer object method is a normal method, does this anonymous object belong to instance level or class level? What if the outer method is static?
2. If the outer object method is called multiple times, would this anonymous object be re-used or re-created?
3. Is such object subject to JVM GC? If yes is the GC rule remaining the same as the other objects?
4. Is there any tool or API to track the life cycle of such anonymous object, given it cannot be referred in the code directly?

Any help or comment or documentation is appreciated.

Comment: 1) and 2) are more or less up to the JVM's implementation, though HotSpot is pretty smart about these things.  3) yes, as normal.  4) you _can_ track it normally; you can assign it directly to the functional interface type and track it normally, if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks. Would be nice if we have some formal documentation somewhere though. For the object passing yes it surely is trackable; but I am wondering about the implementation if such object is embedded. It probably should be the same mechanism but you know, there are sometimes exceptions.

Comment: I have a similar kind of question about life cycle of this anonymous object , if I put create lambda expression in a loop, will Java Runtime create multiple instances of this anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what you mean by "belong". An object doesn't "belong" to any level.
2. If the lambda is a closure, i.e. if it captures one or more local variables from the surrounding scope (including `this` (which is kinda like an implicit `final` local variable), `OuterClass.this` (which is implicitly accessed through a hidden field of `this`), or unqualified instance variables (which are implicitly accessed through `this` or `OuterClass.this`)), then in different times the function containing the lambda expression is evaluated, it will likely have to create different objects, because the values of the captured variables are stored as part of the lambda object, and since in different runs of the function (or even different times within one run of the function), the captured variables can have different values, different lambda objects must be created so that each lambda remembers its separate set of captured values.

   However, if the lambda is not a closure, then any two lambda objects created from that lambda expression are semantically undistinguishable. So then one object can be re-used for all evaluations of that lambda expression. I believe in this case the virtual machine will statically allocate one object for that lambda which lives for the duration of the program.
3. Yes. If an object is created when the lambda expression is run, then it is dynamically allocated like other objects in Java, and it is subject to GC. However, if one object is created for the whole life of the program (see discussion for (2) above), then it would not be memory-managed, similar to string literals.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is just guessing. It's nice if you have any official documentation to confirm the behavior of JVM, or at least Oracle JVM. Of course the JVM "can" re-use it and "can" GC such anonymous objects; but what I am asking if if it "does" re-use or GC them.